# How to load csv data into the database when the source structure and schema structure are not same?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, csv

Let's assume, I have created just the schemas for the tables

```
Student(RollNo,Name,class,Address,EmergencyContactNo)
Course(CourseNo,CourseName)
Student_Course(RollNo,CourseNo)
```

I have the CSV files,which I need to load into the corresponding table.I don't have any problem in loading data into Student table and Course Table since the schema of the table and the csv headers are same. But in **Student_course** table,the schema is **RollNo** and **CourseNo** and the headers of the **StudentCourse.csv** file for the `student_course` is `StudentName` and `CourseName`. In such a case, how do I load the data into the database? Can anyone have solution for this?

```sql
-- Schema for StudentCourse Table

Create  table StudentCourse
(
      id int not null IDENTITY(1,1),
      RollNo varchar(50) ,
      CourseNo varchar(40) ,
      primary key(id)
);
```

> StudentCourse.csv

```
  StudentName,CourseName
  Alwin,CSE
  Brian,CSE
  Cynthia,CSE
  David,CSE
  elizabeth,ECE
  Frank,EEE
  Ganga,ECE
  Hitesh,EEE
  Indra,ECE
  Karthik,ECE
```

Comment: Extract - Transform - Load

Comment: Looking at your schema, it very much seems like `Student_Course` is supposed to be an intersection table for a many-to-many relationship between `Student` and `Course`. You wouldn't want `RollNo` and `CourseNo` to hold the student and course names; rather their respective id/primary key.